# To determine the remainder of the division

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

To determine the remainder of the division of 3<sup>302</sup> + 7<sup>200</sup> with 5.

Is it correct if I find the remainder of the division separately for 3<sup>302</sup> and  7<sup>200</sup> and then add the two of the remainders?

Comment: What do you mean by the 'rest' of the division?  Are you referring to the remainder?

Comment: Yes the remainder, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you would add the remainders of $3^{302}/5$ and $7^{200}/5$ modulo $5$.

Comment: The remainder of 3^302 mod 5 is 4 and the remainder of 7^200 mod 5 is 1.But 5 mod 5 is zero so the remainder is 0?

Comment: Yes.  This is confirmed by @user289143 answer.

Answer (score 2):

The last digit of the powers of $3$ are $3,9,7,1,3,9,..$ they are cyclic and repeating every four times, so the last digit of $3^{302}$ is the same as the last digit of $3^{302 (mod 4)}=3^2=9$. 
Same argument for the last digit of the powers of $7$: $7,9,3,1,7,9...$. Therefore the last digit of $7^{200}$ is the same as the last digit of $7^0=1$. 
Thus the last digit of $3^{302}+7^{200}$ is $9+1=10=0 \ mod \  5$

Comment: It's not 3^202 but 3^302

Comment: Oh sorry. Anyway $302 mod 4 = 202 mod 4 = 2 mod 4$ so the result is the same

Comment: The remainder of 3^302 mod 5 is 4 and the remainder of 7^200 mod 5 is 1. So the result is 4 + 1 = 5. But 5 mod 5 is zero so the remainder is 0? Can I go this way?

Comment: Yes, it’s just another way of saying it

Comment: It's an easier way to calculate for me. I only needed to be sure if I could find the remainders separately. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align}\bmod 5\!:\ \ \ \ &\ \ \ 3^{302}+7^{200}\\ \equiv &\ \ \ 9^{151}+49^{100}\\ \equiv &\ (-1)^{151}\!+(-1)^{100}\\ \equiv &\ \ \ {-1}\ \ +\ \ 1 \end{align}$

using [standard congruence rules](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242), including the Sum Rule (which answers your query affirmatively).